# Cycles baking, one face is in wrong orientation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, baking

When I bake the diffuse of my object (using Cycles) I end up with an okay bake map, except one of the faces of the object bakes incorrectly (wrong scale and orientation).

I refilled the face, re-unwrapped, and re-arranged it but it still does this! Any idea what could be wrong? Thank you in advance!

[image: A cutout of the problem area]

Comment: I see two other white glitches above that, without seeing your object topology, wireframe and resulting UV map it is hard to tell. Look for overlapping geometry in the model and overlapping islands in the UV map

Comment: make sure that the normals for the object are not inverted.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Those are actually windows (lol). But I did look for overlaps in my normal uv-map. Then I created a new uv map(bake_map) and smart projected my entire house onto it. After that I went and looked at the textures again and it seemed fine. Thank you!

Comment: @cegaton, I will go attempt that, thank you! (Baking on my system takes about an hour.)

Comment: Baking albedo map (which is what you seem to be doing, color map without direct / indirect) shouldn't be baked that long as it doesn't depend on samples. Set samples count to 1 while baking passes like e.g Diffuse, Emit

Comment: Well it turns out, if I bake in blender render, everything looks fine. Thank you all!! (I realize that for the game engine I'm using, blender render texturing will be enough)